# Invalid column name Menu_mkey

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

While debugging through the code, I am getting error as

> Invalid column name Menu_mkey

Here is the code for that

```
string strsqlflag = "select count(*) from WMS_User_Rights where User_Id='" + Hid_Selected_user.Value + "'  and delete_flag='N' ";


        if (Dt.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex]["child_menu_mkey"].ToString() == "0")
        {
            strsqlflag += " and  MENU_MKEY = '" + Dt.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex]["MKEY"] + "'";
        }
        else
        {
            strsqlflag += " and  MENU_MKEY = '" + Dt.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex]["child_menu_mkey"] + "'";
        }
```

which generated the below query

```
select count(*) from WMS_User_Rights where User_Id='1'  and delete_flag='N'  and  MENU_MKEY = '1'
```

Now, here I want `Menu_mkey` too, but the issue is that it is coming from another table which is from table `WMS_menu_rights`

How to achieve this ?

on a side note:- I am using `SQL-server 2005`

Comment: Make use of [inner join](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190014(v=sql.105).aspx) to select the values from the two tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use  [SQL Joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) to link those table in query.

for eg:

```
string strsqlflag = "select count(*) from WMS_User_Rights Inner join WMS_Menu_Rights on WMS_User_Rights.somefield=WMS_Menu_Rights.somefield where WMS_User_Rights.User_Id='" + Hid_Selected_user.Value + "'  and WMS_User_Rights.delete_flag='N' ";

    if (Dt.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex]["child_menu_mkey"].ToString() == "0")
    {
        strsqlflag += " and  WMS_Menu_Rights.MENU_MKEY = '" + Dt.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex]["MKEY"] + "'";
    }
    else
    {
        strsqlflag += " and  WMS_Menu_Rights.MENU_MKEY = '" + Dt.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex]["child_menu_mkey"] + "'";
    }
```

Here `somefield` in query `strsqlflag`  represents any field which is common in both tables.

Comment: getting error as `Ambiguous column name 'delete_flag'.`

Comment: check updated code.replaced `delete_flag='N'` with `WMS_User_Rights.delete_flag='N'`.

Comment: +1 for your quick response, Actually it was very easy but couldn't taught off to which column to join with. So i did this and got the count `2`  

`select count(*) from WMS_User_Rights Inner join WMS_Menu_Rights on 
 WMS_User_Rights.User_Id = WMS_Menu_Rights.Mkey where WMS_User_Rights.User_Id='1'  and 
 WMS_User_Rights.delete_flag='N'  and  MENU_MKEY = '1'`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write an `INNER JOIN` query for this :

```
select count(*) from WMS_User_Rights INNER JOIN WMS_menu_rights on WMS_menu_rights.someField = WMS_User_Rights.someField where User_Id='1'  and delete_flag='N' and MENU_MKEY = '1'
```